# SQL Order results by Match Against Relevance and display the price based on sellers rank

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to display results based on 'relevance' of the users search along with the price of the seller that ranks highest. A live example to what i'm after is Amazons search results, now I understand their algorithm is extremely complicated, but i'm after a simplified version.

Lets say we search for 'Jumper' the results that are returned are products related to 'Jumper' but then the price is not always the cheapest is based on the sellers rank. The seller with the highest rank gets his/hers prices displayed.

Heres what I have been working on but not giving me the expected results at mentioned above, and to be honest I don't think this is very efficient.

```
SELECT a.catalogue_id, a.productTitle, a.prod_rank, b.catalogue_id, b.display_price, b.sellers_rank
FROM 

(
    SELECT c.catalogue_id,
           c.productTitle,
           MATCH(c.productTitle) AGAINST ('+jumper*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS prod_rank 
    FROM catalogue AS c
    WHERE c.catalogue_id IN (1, 2, 3)
) a

JOIN 

(
    SELECT inventory.catalogue_id, 
           inventory.amount AS display_price,
           (accounts.comsn + inventory.quantity - inventory.amount) AS sellers_rank

    FROM inventory 
    JOIN accounts ON inventory.account_id = accounts.account_id 
    WHERE inventory.catalogue_id IN (1, 2, 3)
) AS b

ON a.catalogue_id = b.catalogue_id 

ORDER BY a.prod_rank DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Sample Tables:

```
Accounts:
----------------------------
account_id | comsn
----------------------------
1          | 100
2          | 9999




Catalogue:
----------------------------
catalogue_id | productTitle
----------------------------
1            | blue jumper
2            | red jumper
3            | green jumper




Inventory:
-----------------------------------------------
product_id | catalogue_id | account_id | quantity | amount |
-----------------------------------------------
1           | 2           | 1          | 6        | 699
2           | 2           | 2          | 2        | 2999
```

Expected Results:

```
Product Title:
red jumper

Amount:
29.99 (because he/she has sellers rank of: 7002)
```

Comment: I would expect your code to have a `product_id` somewhere.  Perhaps that is what `catalogue_id` is.

Comment: Sorry, yes it does. Must of left it out in this example.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should limit the results only to the matches for the first subquery:

Second, you should eliminate the second subquery:

```
SELECT p.catalogue_id, p.productTitle, p.prod_rank,
       i.amount as display_price,
       (a.comsn + i.quantity - i.amount) 
FROM (SELECT c.catalogue_id, c.productTitle,
             MATCH(c.productTitle) AGAINST ('+jumper*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS prod_rank 
      FROM catalogue AS c
      WHERE c.catalogue_id IN (1, 2, 3)
      HAVING prod_rank > 0
     ) p JOIN 
     inventory i
     ON i.catalogue_id = c.catalogue_id join
     accounts a
     ON i.account_id = a.account_id 
ORDER BY c.prod_rank DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

I'm not sure if you can get rid of the final `ORDER BY`.  `MATCH` with `JOIN` can be a bit tricky in that respect.  But only ordering by the matches should help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how do i display the price from the best seller only. regards.

Comment: Just got your example working, but it displays all the prices available for the product. I also changed (a.comsn + i.quantity - i.amount) AS sellers_rank and added it to the ORDER BY clause.